# How to convert byte array (containing hex values) to decimal

Tags: c, arrays, hex, decimal, atmega

I am writing some code for an Atmel micro-controller. I am getting some data via Uart, and I store these hex values into an array.

Suppose the elements of the array are: 1F, 29, and 3C.

I want to have one hex number like 0x1F293C, and convert it to a decimal number. So, I want to get “2042172” at the end.

The array could have n elements, so I need a general solution.

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how to convert it to a human-readable string, in decimal representation?

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. What is that array? A double array of char, an array of int? And what did you try ?

Comment: The terms 'hex' and 'decimal' refer to string representations of numbers.  So unless you're doing string manipulations, the question reduces to *how to combine three `char` into a single `int`*.   Also note that if your output variable is 32-bits unsigned, then you're limited to `n <= 4`.  With 64-bits unsigned, the limit is `n <= 8`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d", (((unsigned)array[0])<<16)+(((unsigned)array[1])<<8)+(unsigned)array[2];
```

this will write the hex values in `array` to `buffer` as readable string in decimal representation.

assuming `sizeof(int)=4`

Comment: if `array` has signed `char` in it then you need to cast to unsigned char before shifting

Comment: @MattMcNabb took me more than a second to realize why, but yes, that's true. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a array of characters like `"0x1F293C"` and want to convert it to `int` try this code:

```
char receivedByte[] = "0x1F293C";
char *p;
int intNumber = strtol(receivedByte, &p, 16);
printf("The received number is: %ld.\n", intNumber);
```

Comment: The return value of `strtol` is `long int`. If it is necessary you can replace `int intNumber` with `long int intNumber`

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to do. But, how do I get "receivedByte" from an array like;

    char data[] = {0x1F, 0x29, 0x3C}

Comment: @massakrienen Are you sure that `receviedByte` is like that? As I know in UART you get some character like `char ch`

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is declared as stated in the comments (`char data[]={0x1F, 0x29, 0x3C}`), you can run this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char receivedByte[9], *p;
    char data[] = { 0x1F, 0x29, 0x3C };
    sprintf(receivedByte, "0x%X%X%X", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
    int intNumber = strtol(receivedByte, &p, 16);
    printf("The received number is: %ld.\n", intNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input consists of *n* bytes and are stored starting from a pointer `array`, you can add the values up in the order you "received" them - i.e., in the order they are written in the array.

```
unsigned int convertToDecimal (unsigned char *array, int n)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    while (n--)
    {
        result <<= 8;
        result += *array;
        array++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that your sample input contains 3 bytes and you want a "general solution for *n* bytes", and so you may run out of space *really* fast. This function will only work for 0..4 bytes. If you need more bytes, you can switch to `long long` (8 bytes, currently).

For longer sequences than that you need to switch to a BigNum library.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char data[] = {0x1F, 0x29, 0x3C};
    int i, size = sizeof(data);
    unsigned value = 0;

    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        value = value * 256 + (unsigned char)data[i];

    printf("0x%X %d\n", value, (int)value); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for the stated scenario: "I am getting some data via Uart, and I store these hex values into an array." The *actual* array size is known in advance, but the number of elements may vary.

Comment: `size` is represents the number of elements. Because I do not know how to handle a program of OP.