# Convert hex array in C to long in C to String in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, string, long-integer

I have a situation where I have an array of hex characters like the following:

```
// C code
char arr[4];
// Using printf with 0x%02x format specifier, I can see the following contents:
arr[0] --> 0xb2;
arr[1] --> 0x00;
arr[2] --> 0x27;
arr[3] --> 0x79;
```

The above code is in C. I need to convert this array into a long value. The long value has to be then sent into Java code, where it needs to be converted into a string.

```
C array ---> long value ---> Java String
```

The end goal is to get a string in Java initialized as shown below:

```
// Java code
String goal = "b2002779";
```

What would be the recommended way to do this ?

I tried to convert the C char array to long using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341940), but it returned 0. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I suggest you use `unsigned char` unless `0xb2` is intended to be negative. `long` is signed.

Comment: When you say `long`, is it a C `long` (32 bits) or a Java `long` (64 bits) ?

Comment: NB: your input array is not "hex characters". That was the way you defined it as humanly readable. An `unsigned char` array knows nothing about hex, they are binary values. If you want "hex characters" then define as a string and pass that string to java. `char myhex[] = "b2002779";`

Comment: Is the intermediary step of converting to a long actually necessary? Regardless, more importantly, how do you intend to get this over to Java? Are you receiving the value in Java via some form of process communication (sockets)? Is the value getting to Java via JNI? Perhaps the value is being saved to a file and read by a Java process? Or are you actually wanting the string hexadecimal representation of the number to be saved to a into a `.java` file?

Comment: @SpencerDoak It will be sent via sockets.

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited the question

Comment: When you read the `int` value in Java, just use `Integer.toHexString`.

Comment: In reality a number inside variable isnt hex, decimal or octal. Hex can be in externeal presentation

Answer (score 1):

You can append these unsigned char values using `sprintf`, then convert to a base 10 `long` using `atol`

```
unsigned char b[] = { 0xb2, 0xa1, 0xc3 };

char s[20];
sprintf(s, "%d%d%d", b[0], b[1], b[2]);

long n = atol(s);
```

Then with the either 32 or 64 bit value (depending on your system) in base 10 in java, you can use `Integer.toHexString` to convert to a hex string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the conversion on the c++ side.
Use something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char map[16];

void convert(unsigned short decimal, char* buffer) {
  if (decimal > 255) {
    return;
  } else if (decimal < 16) {
    buffer[0]='0';
    buffer[0]=map[decimal];
  } else {
    unsigned short remainder=decimal%16;
    unsigned short multiplier=(decimal-remainder)/16;
    buffer[0]=map[multiplier];
    buffer[1]=map[remainder];
  }

  printf("conversion %d to %s\n", decimal, buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  map[0]='0';
  map[1]='1';
  map[2]='2';
  map[3]='3';
  map[4]='4';
  map[5]='5';
  map[6]='6';
  map[7]='7';
  map[8]='8';
  map[9]='9';
  map[10]='A';
  map[11]='B';
  map[12]='C';
  map[13]='D';
  map[14]='E';
  map[15]='F';

  unsigned short arr[4];
  arr[0] = 0xb2;
  arr[1] = 0x00;
  arr[2] = 0x27;
  arr[3] = 0x79;

  printf("%i.%i.%i.%i\n",
         arr[0], 
         arr[1], 
         arr[2],
         arr[3]);

  static char buffer[9];

  for(int x=0; x<4; x++) {
    static char buffer1[3];
    memset(buffer1, 0, sizeof(buffer1));
    convert(arr[x], buffer1);
    strcat(buffer, buffer1);
  }

  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```